# py.test doesn't collect tests that are not inherited from 'object'

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pytest

I'm trying to create **Base** class with different setups I need for my tests. I want all my tests to be inherited from this **Base** class. As runner I use [py.test](http://pytest.org).

But when I'm trying to do so, py.test doesn't collect these tests inherited from **Base** class, and as a result it doesn't run them. Didn't find any useful info in documentation.

Maybe someone faced such issues before? Any ideas?

Thanks.

P.S. When tests are inherited from **object** everything works fine. Py.test see them and run correctly.

Example of code:

My Base class:

```
class BaseClass(object):
"""BaseClass"""
def __init__(self):
    super(BaseClass, self).__init__()
    self.bla = 'bla'
```

My Test class:

```
import pytest
from base_class import BaseClass

class TestSmth(BaseClass):
    def test_test(self):
        test_instatnce = TestSmth()
        print test_instatnce.bla

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([__file__, '-v'])
```

Output:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.2 -- pytest-2.3.3 -- /usr/bin/python
collecting ... collected 0 items

===============================  in 0.01 seconds ===============================
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can use `__init__`. If you what to setup (or initialize) the Class you can do :

```
# base_class.py

class BaseClass(object):
"""BaseClass"""

    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope = "class", autouse = True)
    def setup(self):
        self.bla = 'bla'

#test_class.py

import pytest
from base_class import BaseClass

class TestSmth(BaseClass):
    def test_test(self):
        print self.bla

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([__file__, '-v'])
```

Also to initialize the `TestSmth` class you can create another "method" and decorate it with `@pytest.fixture` as well. HOWEVER, you must remember that those **"initialization methods" are called in alphabetical order**.

Comment: The fixture functions are sorted by scope, so all class-scoped fixtures will execute before function-scoped ones.  Within each scope the order is not defined, might be alphabetical but that would be co-incidental.

Comment: @hpk42, It's in alphabetical within a class. :) You can try it for yourself: https://bitbucket.org/alex_okrushko/pytest-class-init-order/commits/e3f316d6597c57e22a82362643197140

Comment: not claiming it's not alphabetical, please just don't rely on it :)